# Does my coffee pot need to be fixed?

Tags: flavor, drip-brew

So, I have this GREAT cocoa coffee. It is literally the best coffee I have ever tasted. I know, big statement. Anyways, I recently moved out and had to buy a new coffee pot. :(

Well, my coffee consumption went from 100 to 0 real quick because of the taste I've been getting with this new coffee pot. I've tried tap water and bottled water and it doesn't change anything. It just tastes like.... well it tastes like crap.

Any suggestions on how to fix it? I'd love to drink coffee every morning again without having to pay $2 for a large cup of Biggby's coffee. :-)

(Also, if someone could create a new tag called coffee-pot that'd be fantastic and useful :-) )

It's just a cheap $25 5-cup Mr.Coffee as well!

Comment: It would be interesting to know more about what is different between the two setups: what kind (brand?) of pots they are, whether you are using different filters, how you stored the coffee itself, etc. Also what kind of "crap" taste do you get? Bitter? Something else?

Comment: Its a really hard taste to explain. @dhag , I'll add the details later, I'm at work now. :-)

Comment: there are tags for the various different kinds of coffee makers. Auto-drip, percolator, etc

Comment: I guess mine would be considered an "auto-drip" then? It's just a cheap $25 5-cup Mr.Coffee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could be more specific with your question it would be easier to answer.  For example was your previous "pot" a percolator or automatic coffee maker or what?  By the same token, what is your current set up?  By a process of elimination you should be able to isolate the factor that's causing your coffee to taste sh***ty.  Basically those are:

1. The coffee itself - is it from the same source, being stored the same, same age, etc.
2. Same water - you said you'd tried different water sources.  Bottled water should yield good coffee.
3. The method of brewing, which would include water temperature, coarseness of grind, how long it extracts (steeps), cleanliness of the equipment, etc.

If all the factors except the method of brewing are accounted for, then the problem is in the brewing method, which would include the coffee maker.  If you know it's clean and it still tastes bad, you need a different brewing method.  Depending on how much coffee you drink, there are lots of options that will yield good coffee.  I have found that the simpler methods (i.e., French press, AeroPress, pour over) are the easiest to control and therefore give you the best chance of getting a good result.  They are also cheaper and easier to keep clean.  Brewing good coffee is actually pretty straightforward so don't give up!